# Is Future's timeout method broken?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have a long running task that I want to run asynchronously with a Future, but I also want it to timeout eventually.  It seems to me that my timeout is never being called - but perhaps I am not using timeout correctly?

```dart
// do actual solution finding asychronously
Future populateFuture = new Future(() {
  populateGrid(words, gridWidth, gridHeight);
});
populateFuture.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3), onTimeout: () {
  window.alert("Could not create a word search in a reasonable amount of time.");
});

// after being done, draw it if one was found
populateFuture.then((junk) {
  wordSearchGrid.drawOnce();
});
```

This is under version 1.3.0-dev.4.1  Perhaps I am just misunderstanding how to use timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart has [a single thread of execution](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/#darts-single-thread-of-execution).

> Once a Dart function starts executing, it continues executing until it exits. In other words, Dart functions can’t be interrupted by other Dart code.

If `populateGrid` doesn't allow [the event loop](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/#event-loops-and-queues) to switch to the `timeout` part the `timeout` checks will not be executed. That means you have to *break* the code of `populateGrid` into several part by introducing `Future` computations to allow regular checks by the `timeout` function.

Answer (score 3):

An example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

void main(args) {
  var f = new Future(()=>burnCpu());
  f.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));
}

bool signal = false;

int i = 0;
var r = new Random();

Future burnCpu() {
  if (i < 1000000) {
    i++;
    return new Future(() { // can only interrupt here
      print(i);
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
        var a = (j / r.nextDouble()).toString() + r.nextDouble().toString();

      }
    }).then((e) => burnCpu());
  } else {
    return new Future.value('end');
  }
}
```