# Dart async/await encapsulation

Tags: dart, dart-async

I want to return fractional of a decimal, but if the function takes too much time, the function must give up. I tried this, but it doesn't work... I probably did something wrong. Could you to show me my mistake?

```dart
String decimalToFractional(double d) async {
  var df = 1.0;
  var top = 1;
  var bot = 1;

  var future = new Future<String>(() {
    while (df != d) {
      if (df < d) {
        top += 1;
      } else {
        bot += 1;
        top = (d * bot).toInt();
      }
      df = top / bot;
    }
    return new Future.value('$top/$bot');
  });
  future.timeout(new Duration(seconds: 2), onTimeout: () => new Future.value(d.toString()));
  return await future;
}
```

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: I get an instance of future instead of a value.

Comment: The close vote is totally unnecessary. This question is quite clear and a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: You are trying to approximate a double by a fraction. Since all doubles are binary values, they are always fractions of a power of 2. If you want an approximation that is not precise but close enough, it might be faster to start with the int/2^n fraction that instead of starting from scratch. You  are likely losing precision in the multiplications and divisions you are doing anyway.

Comment: @Irn I'm not sure to understand, could you provide an example ?

Comment: Doubles are represented as an integer times a power of two. That means that a fractional value (negative power of two) is always exactly that integer divided by a power of two. You can find the integer and power much simpler than the searching you do, see: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0c00e388f74d334b8758 . That doesn't mean that there isn't some other fraction that happens to generate the same double value due to rounding, and your code might find that eventually. I'm *guessing* that you might be able to find such a fraction sooner by starting from the exact fraction, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code.
If you want to return the result of an async operation the return type has to be `Future<...>`

```
Future<String> decimalToFractional(double d) async {
```

You can then consume the result like

```
main() async {
  print(await decimalToFractional(123456789.123456789));
}
```

If you want timeout to take effect you need to return to the event loop. As long as sync execution is running timeout doesn't fire.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22473556/217408

Comment: This won't work, for the reason you state above - for a timer to work, control needs to return to the event loop. The timedOut variable is never set to true while the loop is running. What you can do instead is use a stopwatch: `var sw = new StopWatch()..start(); while (df != d) { if (sw.elapsedMilliseconds >= 2000) { return "$top/$bot"; }; ...} `.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I wondered why it worked but it seemed it did. Have to check closer.

Comment: If seems the sync version was just a lot faster and `timedOut`  was set to `true` after it was already finished.